# File(resume) upload using spring-mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, file-upload, spring-mvc

I am uploading a file (a Microsoft office word document) using spring mvc.
For that I am using spring `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`.
I'm able to upload the file but facing problems in storing it in a MySQL database.
When I save the file as multipartFile obtained from the form submission (`MultipartFile multipartFile = employee.getFile();`). It's saved in the database as object named as

> org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@1c79dfc.

I want to store the data as string (present in the file). How do I convert multipartFile in string format such that I can save it in a MySQL database using type TEXT.

Here's the info on multipartFile:

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = employee.getFile();
byte[] content=multipartFile.getBytes();
String s = new String(content);
log.info ("size:"+multipartFile.getSize());
```

Output:

> size:10066

```
log.info ("content type:"+multipartFile.getContentType());
```

Output:

> content
>   type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

```
log.info("Filename:"+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
```

Output:

> Filename:prabhat-resume.docx

I want to save it in the database as a TEXT blob. What do I need to do?

Comment: A Word document is binary.  What do you want to store?  The bytes?

Comment: @Aaron i want to store in string formate or the file will be stored on disk and i will like to store path with time stamp. any one is acceptable but last one is preferred

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a new File and transfer a MultipartFile object to it.  There is even a method provided to make this easy.

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = employee.getFile();
File localFile = new File("location/"+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
multipartFile.transferTo(localFile);
```

From there you can store the location of the localFile to your MySQL database.